# Linear Color Gradient in openCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

i am trying to create gradient of two colors like Photoshop.
r,g,b of two colors is input and result will be the Mat of gradient. I tried it like for 5 hours at least and i could not find exact effect as of the Photoshop.
I tried to create my own formula (as i could not find any on the web), by changing RGB to HSV and then adding the difference of hue, with respect to the total number of rows, to each row of Mat with and also decreasing intensity to the center of image and then increasing it again. The code is self explanatory.

Additionally if anyone can tell me the exact formula for creating a gradient it will be really helpful.

here is how Photoshop gradient looks like

[image]

and this is what i get from my code[image]

```
 int r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2;

 r1 = 255;
 g1 = 0;
 b1 = 0;
 r2 = 0;
 g2 = 255;
 b2 = 0;

 Mat input = imread("img.jpg");
 Mat color1(input.size(), input.type());
 Mat color2(input.size(), input.type());

 vector<Mat> bgr1;
 vector<Mat> bgr2;

 split(color1, bgr1);
 bgr1[0] = b1;
 bgr1[1] = g1;
 bgr1[2] = r1;
 merge(bgr1, color1);

 split(color2, bgr2);
 bgr2[0] = b2;
 bgr2[1] = g2;
 bgr2[2] = r2;
 merge(bgr2, color2);

 vector<Mat> hls1;
 vector<Mat> hls2;

 cvtColor(color1, color1, CV_BGRA2BGR);
 cvtColor(color1, color1, CV_BGR2HSV);
 split(color1, hls1);

 cvtColor(color2, color2, CV_BGRA2BGR);
 cvtColor(color2, color2, CV_BGR2HSV);
 split(color2, hls2);

 double h1 = hls1[0].at<uchar>(0, 0);
 double h2 = hls2[0].at<uchar>(0, 0);
 double dif = (h2 - h1) / input.rows;
 double h = h1;

 double halfL = 255 / 2;
 double halfR = input.rows / 2;
 double ldif = halfL / halfR;
 double l = 255;
 bool isHalf = false;

 for (int i = 0; i < input.rows; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < input.cols; j++)
  {
   hls1[0].at<uchar>(i, j) = h;
   hls1[2].at<uchar>(i, j) = l;
  }


  if (isHalf == false){
   l -= ldif;
  }
  else{
   l += ldif;
  }

  if (i < input.rows * 0.40)
  {
   h += dif * 0.40;
  }
  else if (i < input.rows * 0.60)
  {
   h += dif * 3;
  }
  else
  {
   h += dif * 0.40;
  }

  if (i >= input.rows / 2)
  {
   isHalf = true;
  }
 }

 merge(hls1, color1);
 merge(hls2, color2);

 cvtColor(color1, color1, CV_HSV2BGR);
 cvtColor(color1, color1, CV_BGR2BGRA);

 cvtColor(color2, color2, CV_HSV2BGR);
 cvtColor(color2, color2, CV_BGR2BGRA);

 namedWindow("Color1", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
 resizeWindow("Color1", color1.size().width / 2, color1.size().height / 2);
 imshow("Color1", color1);

 waitKey(0);
 destroyAllWindows();
 system("pause");
```

Comment: btw, it's a computer-vision library, not photoshop..

Answer (score 11):

*I corrected my first code*

It seems to be a really complex code for something that should be easier.
I would do something like that.

```
int taille = 500;    
Mat image(taille,taille,CV_8UC3);
for(int y = 0; y < taille; y++){
   Vec3b val;
   val[0] = 0; val[1] = (y*255)/taille; val[2] = (taille-y)*255/taille;
   for(int x = 0; x < taille; x++)
      image.at<Vec3b>(y,x) = val;
}
```

On Micka's advice, I add a picture of the result with taille = 400;
[image: Result of the previous code.]

Comment: Here, I made a really linear gradient. You could have something different by changing the formulae computing val.

Comment: if you post a picture with your result (and it looks more like the desired result of the poster), you'll probably get many upvotes =)

Comment: Thanks, for the advice, I edited the first message to add an image.

Comment: Thanks for your help biquette, your code works fine as for the given condition but what i intend to do is that given the input two colors, with (r1,g1,b1) and (r2,g2,b2), a dynamic gradient formula that will work for any two colors and create gradient for them. Can you please help me with that also?

Comment: Ok, I get what you want. In that case, replace the computation of val. Just after the declaration of image, declare two Vec3b color1(b1,g1,r1) and color2(b2,g2,r2). Then the computation of val is val[i] = (y*color1 + (taille-y)*color2)/taille;