# Change formula for Linear gradient to radial gradient Android OpenCv C++

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I followed the answer from biquette to make a linear gradient
[Linear Color Gradient in openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622612/linear-color-gradient-in-opencv)
and it works perfectly fine can anyone tell me how to change this formula to radial gradient

```
Vec3b val;
val[0] = (y*color1[0] + (height - y)*color2[0]) / height;
val[1] = (y*color1[1] + (height - y)*color2[1]) / height;
val[2] = (y*color1[2] + (height - y)*color2[2]) / height;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: well it's basically that shrunk down to a line and spun around...

Comment: Just use Euclidian distance in color mixing coefficient calculation.